# Trying To Store Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

```
<input id="value">
```

app.js has

```
var userNum = $('#value').val();
```

load browser and type 10

now in chrome console I type userNum but it shows ""

Why is it "" and not 10

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I've added the val() and typing userNum in chrome console still gives ""

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the value.

```
var userNum = $('#value').val();
```

Then you send it to the console

```
console.log(userNum);
```

**EDIT**

You need to attach an eventListener so you can get the value from the input. [VIEW DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fvaz3bx0/1/)

Comment: Modify to what you have but same result. Edited my post to see if that makes more sense. Thanks for helping.

Comment: eventListener was the key. Thank you for your help Josan!

Answer (score 0):

To actually grab the value inside the input, you need to use `val()`.

```
var useNum = $('#value').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input id="value" type="text">
```

And JQuery:

var userNum = $('#value').value();

Comment: this will not work. it gives Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: Look this http://jsfiddle.net/82t1qwz9/ . The jquery code must be inside on $(document).ready(function () { var userNum = $('#value').value(); }); and put html value for print some string <input id="value" type="text" value="helloworld">

Answer (score 0):

The reason why is because you assigned the value of the object $('#value') to userNum instead of the string in $('#value'). To get the string in $('#value') you use $('#value').val().

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that`var userNum = $('#value');`is selecting the DOM element with the id of value. If you want the actual value in that element, you need to us the .val() method like this:

```
var userNum = $('#value').val();
```

However, unless you input has a value when the script loads, userNum will still be set to ''.

Comment: Your last sentence explains it. Is there a way to retrieve val after browser load and new input?

Comment: It would be pretty easy if you had a button the user would press. You could set up an event listener for a click on the button and assign the value in the input to the userNum variable when that event occurs. Otherwise, you may be able to use the change event listener on the input field. I am not sure if that would work though. I would need to try it out.